# Reverse the order in the recursive query that gets all parents of an item

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my query: Link to [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/345ca/19)

```
with fruit_tree as 
(
   select [FRUIT_ID], [PARENT_FRUIT]
   ,CAST(FRUIT_NAME AS VARCHAR(max)) AS tree
   from FRUIT
   where [FRUIT_ID] = 'B03'
   union all
   select C.[FRUIT_ID], C.[PARENT_FRUIT]
   ,CAST(tree + ',' + CAST(c.FRUIT_NAME AS VARCHAR(max)) AS VARCHAR(max))
   from FRUIT c     
   join fruit_tree p on C.[FRUIT_ID] = P.[PARENT_FRUIT]
    AND C.[FRUIT_ID]<>C.[PARENT_FRUIT] 
)
select * from fruit_tree
where [PARENT_FRUIT] = '0'
```

Above query gives output as:

```
FRUIT_ID    PARENT_FRUIT    tree
FR03        0               GOLDER BEAUTY,BANANA
```

But I need output as:

```
FRUIT_ID    PARENT_FRUIT    tree
FR03        0               BANANA,GOLDER BEAUTY
```

How could I achieve this? Link to [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/345ca/19)

Comment: pretty sure this kind of thing has been asked before, let me find a duplicate for you...

Comment: Put tree behind your cast? ,CAST( CAST(c.FRUIT_NAME AS VARCHAR(max))+ ',' + tree  AS VARCHAR(max))

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/345ca/22

Comment: i don't understand the hardcoded  'B03' in the first union, what is the query you want to do? 'Recursive query that gets all parents of an item' with parameter PARENT_ID = 0. so the first union what is for?

Comment: @LucaMazzanti Thanks for your cooperation. I got the answer for my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to reverse the order in the third column of the output, then change this:

```
,CAST(tree + ',' + CAST(c.FRUIT_NAME AS VARCHAR(max)) AS VARCHAR(max))
```

to:

```
,CAST(CAST(c.FRUIT_NAME AS VARCHAR(max)) + ',' + tree AS VARCHAR(max))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yeah I just wanted to reverse the order  in the third column of the output.